# android listview only button change

Tags: android, button, onclick, adapter, listitem

I want to make a button in `listView` at each `listItem`. And this button is `setOnClickListener()`; When I click this button, I want to change only this button at `ItemView` at position with not using `notifyDatasetChanged()` .
This method is all refresh list `ItemViews`. I dont want to refresh all Items. 
How should I do?

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Comment: what you want to change when click button? and better show your `getView()` codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RecyclerView
http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

> Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events

you need android support library

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a solution I have found.